# Anaerobic Cycling Power analysis - ANCOVA or paired-t tests?

Tags: t-test, ancova

I collected anaerobic power during a cycle stationary cycle test (Wingate) for 30 seconds. During one trial the cyclist performed the test using a traditional cycling technique. One the other day, subjects were instructed to rotate their hips - exaggerated movement in the transverse plane at the half-way point. I want to see if there is a significant difference in the Fatigue Index ((peak power-min/peak) x 100), mean power and minimum power for the two interventions during the last 15 seconds of the test. My question is, do I use peak power as a covariate and run an ANCOVA with post-hoc or should I just run a paired t-test?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an *a priori* hypotheses as to why peak power output would explain changes within the Fatigue Index, mean power, and minimum power?

Usually, covariates are independent of treatment (http://dawg.utk.edu/glossary/whatis_covariate.htm), which may suggest using peak power is improper given that it is measured within the current study.

Being in physiology and familiar with the Wingate, a paired samples t test is likely the best option. You may want to investigate further with regression analyses based around peak power and your other dependent variables.